# tar -h with symlinks pointing to themselves

Tags: bash, symlink, tar

I have a pretty bad issue where when I tar a series of directories, I want to remove symlinks and tar the file they belong to. I do this using -h option which works perfectly fine up until I have a directory which is symlinked to the directory above.

For Example:

```
 /etc/versions/product
    product.php
    product2.php
    product -> /etc/versions/product
```

Is there a way to skip these directories or only follow the symlink once? I do have an excludes list however I do not fancy going through the entire system and excluding them individually unless it is the only option

this is the command im using, im sorry I cannot be more specific than that:

```
tar cvzfh ${BACKUP} --exclude-from ${EXCLUDES_FILE} ${MYSQLFILES} ${LDAP_FILE} ${PATHS}
```

Comment: It looks like maybe you only want to follow links that point to files, not to directories... But I don't know that `tar` can do that on it's own - you may need to do some pre-processing of your file list and feed that to tar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out using `find` to find any symlinks with loop to themselves.

```
find **path** -follow > /dev/null 2>/tmp/symlinkFiles && cat /tmp/symlinkFiles | awk '{print $4}'
```